# why does overriding values.yaml of a helm chart, still show default values.yaml?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am trying to use helm chart for airflow on K8s with custom values.yaml file for my credentials following the tutorial on airflow website with these commands.

```
kubectl create ns airflow
helm repo add apache-airflow https://airflow.apache.org
```

After this, I created a new values.yaml file where I have custom credentials for airflow UI and datbase. After which I used,

```
helm upgrade --install airflow apache-airflow/airflow -f ./values.yaml -n airflow
```

This upgrades my airflow and shows new values.yaml on screen but the login credentials seems to be the default ones on the airflow release.

I see an updated revision when I look for

```
helm ls -n airflow
```

It doesn't show any other errors but values doesn't look like my custom ones, eventhough it prints them on screen.

How do I make sure that my values.yaml is overwritten here?

Comment: airflow, afaik, will install multiple pods in the `airflow` namespaces, so all those values that you are care about will go to one of those pods (or many). So may be a `kubectl describe ...` will help? Also : "It doesn't show any other errors but values doesn't look like my custom ones, eventhough it prints them on screen." - for someone that does not know what `airflow` is, will make no sense.